# Apply function repeatedly a specific number of times

Tags: function, julia

If you have a function, is there an easy or built-in way to apply it `n` times, or until the result is something specific. So, for example, if you want to apply the `sqrt` function 4 times, with the effect of:

```
julia> sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(11231))))
1.791229164345863
```

you could type something like:

```
repeatf(sqrt, 11231, 4)
```

Comment: how about recursion? `repeatf(fn, x, n) = n == 1 ? fn(x) : repeatf(fn, fn(x), n-1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Edit: See bottom for simple solution without Iterators, though I suggest using it and all the useful functions inside the package]

With Iterators package, the following could be a solution:

```
julia> using Iterators   # install with Pkg.add("Iterators")
julia> reduce((x,y)->y,take(iterate(sqrt,11231.0),5))
1.791229164345863
```

`iterate` does the composition logic (Do `?iterate` on the REPL for description). The newer version of Iterators (still untagged) has a function called `nth`, which would make this even simpler:

```
nth(iterate(sqrt,11231.0),5)
```

As a side note, the `(x,y)->y` anonymous function could nicely be defined with a name since it could potentially be used often with `reduce` as in:

```
first(x,y) = x
second(x,y) = y
```

Now,

```
julia> reduce(second,take(iterate(sqrt,11231.0),5))
1.791229164345863
```

works. Also, without recursion (which entails stack allocation and waste), and allocation proportional to the depth of iteration, this could be more efficient, especially for higher iteration values than 5.

**Without the Iterators package**, a simple solution using `foldl` is

```
julia> foldl((x,y)->sqrt(x),1:4, init=11231.0)
1.791229164345863
```

As before, the reduction operation is key, this time it applies `sqrt` but ignores the iterator values which are only used to set the number of times the function is applied (perhaps a different iterator or vector than `1:4` could be used in the application for better readability of code)

Comment: Cool, so you *can* do it with `reduce` - I tried that but it said it wanted a binary operator...

Answer (score 7):

I dont know of such a function but you could use this

```
julia> repeatf(f, x, n) = n > 1 ? f(repeatf(f, x, n-1)) : f(x)

julia> repeatf(sqrt, 11321, 4)
 106.40018796975878
```

also, even comfier

```
repeatf(n, f, x...) = n > 1 ? f(repeatf(n-1, f, x...)...) : f(x...)
```

for functions with more than one arguement

Answer (score 7):

I'm a fan of defining that `^` operator to work on `Function`s and `Int`s

```
julia> (^)(f::Function, i::Int) = i==1 ? f : x->(f^(i-1))(f(x))
^ (generic function with 1 method)

julia> (sqrt^1)(2)
1.4142135623730951

julia> (sqrt^2)(2)
1.189207115002721

julia> (sqrt^3)(2)
1.0905077326652577
```

As @DNF points out, because julia has no Tail Call Optimization,
it is better to do this iteratively;

```
    julia> function (∧)(f::Function, i::Int)
               function inner(x)
                  for ii in i:-1:1
                     x=f(x)
                  end
               x
               end
           end


After warmup:

    julia> @time((sqrt ∧ 1_000)(20e300)) #Iterative
      0.000018 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)
    1.0
    
    julia> @time((sqrt ^ 1_000)(20e300)) #Recursive
      0.000522 seconds (2.00 k allocations: 31.391 KB)
    1.0
    
    #########
    
    julia> @time((sqrt ∧ 10_000)(20e300)) #Iterative
      0.000091 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)
    1.0
    
    
    julia> @time((sqrt ^ 10_000)(20e300)) #Recursive
      0.003784 seconds (20.00 k allocations: 312.641 KB)
    1.0
    
    #########
    
    julia> @time((sqrt ∧ 30_000)(20e300)) # Iterative
      0.000224 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)
    1.0

    julia> @time((sqrt ^ 30_000)(20e300)) #Recursive
      0.008128 seconds (60.00 k allocations: 937.641 KB)
    1.0
    
    
    #############
   
    julia> @time((sqrt ∧ 100_000)(20e300)) #Iterative
      0.000393 seconds (6 allocations: 192 bytes)
    1.0

    julia> @time((sqrt ^ 100_000)(20e300)) #Recursive
    ERROR: StackOverflowError:
     in (::##5#6{Base.#sqrt,Int64})(::Float64) at ./REPL[1]:1 (repeats 26667 times)



The overhead isn't too bad in this case, but that `StackOverflowError` at the end is a kicker.
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. I took your idea and implemented it as a repeated application in a loop, thinking that since Julia does not have tail call optimization it would be more efficient. The `@code_native` output is *much* shorter for my code than yours, but the performance is identical (down to a hundredth of a microsecond) for `sqrt` applied 1000 times.

Comment: @DNF that is because you 1000 is not enough.  I'll update the answer

Comment: I did try with 10^6 too, though, and still no difference. How many do you think is needed?

Comment: what version are you on? I was using v0.5rc0. 10^6 just stack-overflows for me.

Comment: Hmm. Using 0.5 release version.

Comment: Why not use higher order functions? `(^)(f::Function, n::Integer) = x -> reduce((x, _) -> f(x), 1:n; init = x)
`

Comment: You can also avoid the lambda function by using the `\circ` operator and support the `i=0` case with `identity`: `(^)(f::Function, i::Int) = i==0 ? identity : f^(i-1)∘f`

Answer (score 3):

```
function apply(f, x, n=1)
    for _ in 1:n
        x = f(x)
    end
    return x
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I find neither of the above answers satisfying. They all work, but none of them are truly elegant. My personal favorite is this:

```
Base.repeat(f::Function, n::Integer) = reduce(∘, fill(f, n))
```

Of course, you don't even need to define `repeat`, you can just use the `reduce(...)` construct directly.

And this is how it would be used in the case of the original example:

```
julia> repeat(sqrt, 4)(11231)
1.791229164345863
```

or

```
julia> reduce(∘, fill(sqrt, 4))(11231)
1.791229164345863
```